# ClassCastError: getMainModel() calls the Error

Tags: java, exception, minecraft

The Error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: net.minecraft.client.model.ModelZombie cannot be cast to net.minecraft.client.model.ModelPlayer
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.entity.RenderPlayer.getMainModel(RenderPlayer.java:42)
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.entity.RenderPlayer.renderRightArm(RenderPlayer.java:122)
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.ItemRenderer.func_178095_a(ItemRenderer.java:207)
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.ItemRenderer.renderItemInFirstPerson(ItemRenderer.java:322)
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.EntityRenderer.renderHand(EntityRenderer.java:1018)
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.EntityRenderer.renderHand(EntityRenderer.java:963)
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.EntityRenderer.renderWorldPass(EntityRenderer.java:1898)
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.EntityRenderer.renderWorld(EntityRenderer.java:1528)
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.EntityRenderer.func_181560_a(EntityRenderer.java:1326)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.runGameLoop(Minecraft.java:1129)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(Minecraft.java:421)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:113)
    at Start.main(Start.java:11)
```

### A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:

```
-- Head --
Stacktrace:
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.entity.RenderPlayer.getMainModel(RenderPlayer.java:42)
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.entity.RenderPlayer.renderRightArm(RenderPlayer.java:122)
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.ItemRenderer.func_178095_a(ItemRenderer.java:207)
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.ItemRenderer.renderItemInFirstPerson(ItemRenderer.java:322)
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.EntityRenderer.renderHand(EntityRenderer.java:1018)
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.EntityRenderer.renderHand(EntityRenderer.java:963)
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.EntityRenderer.renderWorldPass(EntityRenderer.java:1898)
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.EntityRenderer.renderWorld(EntityRenderer.java:1528)
```

Class which calls the Error:

```java
package net.minecraft.client.renderer.entity;

import net.minecraft.client.entity.AbstractClientPlayer;
import net.minecraft.client.model.ModelBase;
import net.minecraft.client.model.ModelPlayer;
import net.minecraft.client.renderer.GlStateManager;
import net.minecraft.client.renderer.entity.layers.LayerArrow;
import net.minecraft.client.renderer.entity.layers.LayerBipedArmor;
import net.minecraft.client.renderer.entity.layers.LayerCape;
import net.minecraft.client.renderer.entity.layers.LayerCustomHead;
import net.minecraft.client.renderer.entity.layers.LayerDeadmau5Head;
import net.minecraft.client.renderer.entity.layers.LayerHeldItem;
import net.minecraft.entity.Entity;
import net.minecraft.entity.EntityLivingBase;
import net.minecraft.entity.player.EnumPlayerModelParts;
import net.minecraft.item.EnumAction;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemStack;
import net.minecraft.scoreboard.Score;
import net.minecraft.scoreboard.ScoreObjective;
import net.minecraft.scoreboard.Scoreboard;
import net.minecraft.util.ResourceLocation;

public class RenderPlayer extends RendererLivingEntity<AbstractClientPlayer> {
  private boolean smallArms;
  
  public RenderPlayer(RenderManager renderManager) {
    this(renderManager, false);
  }
  
  public RenderPlayer(RenderManager renderManager, boolean useSmallArms) {
    super(renderManager, (ModelBase)new ModelPlayer(0.0F, useSmallArms), 0.5F);
    this.smallArms = useSmallArms;
    addLayer(new LayerBipedArmor(this));
    addLayer(new LayerHeldItem(this));
    addLayer(new LayerArrow(this));
    addLayer(new LayerDeadmau5Head(this));
    addLayer(new LayerCape(this));
    addLayer(new LayerCustomHead((getMainModel()).bipedHead));
  }
  
  public ModelPlayer getMainModel() {
    return (ModelPlayer)super.getMainModel();
  }
  
  public void setMainModel(float scale) {
    this.mainModel = (ModelBase)new ModelPlayer(scale, this.smallArms);
  }
  
  public void doRender(AbstractClientPlayer entity, double x, double y, double z, float entityYaw, float partialTicks) {
    if (!entity.isUser() || this.renderManager.livingPlayer == entity) {
      double d0 = y;
      if (entity.isSneaking() && !(entity instanceof net.minecraft.client.entity.EntityPlayerSP))
        d0 = y - 0.125D; 
      setModelVisibilities(entity);
      super.doRender(entity, x, d0, z, entityYaw, partialTicks);
    } 
  }
  
  private void setModelVisibilities(AbstractClientPlayer clientPlayer) {
    ModelPlayer modelplayer = getMainModel();
    if (clientPlayer.isSpectator()) {
      modelplayer.setInvisible(false);
      modelplayer.bipedHead.showModel = true;
      modelplayer.bipedHeadwear.showModel = true;
    } else {
      ItemStack itemstack = clientPlayer.inventory.getCurrentItem();
      modelplayer.setInvisible(true);
      modelplayer.bipedHeadwear.showModel = clientPlayer.isWearing(EnumPlayerModelParts.HAT);
      modelplayer.bipedBodyWear.showModel = clientPlayer.isWearing(EnumPlayerModelParts.JACKET);
      modelplayer.bipedLeftLegwear.showModel = clientPlayer.isWearing(EnumPlayerModelParts.LEFT_PANTS_LEG);
      modelplayer.bipedRightLegwear.showModel = clientPlayer.isWearing(EnumPlayerModelParts.RIGHT_PANTS_LEG);
      modelplayer.bipedLeftArmwear.showModel = clientPlayer.isWearing(EnumPlayerModelParts.LEFT_SLEEVE);
      modelplayer.bipedRightArmwear.showModel = clientPlayer.isWearing(EnumPlayerModelParts.RIGHT_SLEEVE);
      modelplayer.heldItemLeft = 0;
      modelplayer.aimedBow = false;
      modelplayer.isSneak = clientPlayer.isSneaking();
      if (itemstack == null) {
        modelplayer.heldItemRight = 0;
      } else {
        modelplayer.heldItemRight = 1;
        if (clientPlayer.getItemInUseCount() > 0) {
          EnumAction enumaction = itemstack.getItemUseAction();
          if (enumaction == EnumAction.BLOCK) {
            modelplayer.heldItemRight = 3;
          } else if (enumaction == EnumAction.BOW) {
            modelplayer.aimedBow = true;
          } 
        } 
      } 
    } 
  }
  
  protected ResourceLocation getEntityTexture(AbstractClientPlayer entity) {
    return entity.getLocationSkin();
  }
  
  public void transformHeldFull3DItemLayer() {
    GlStateManager.translate(0.0F, 0.1875F, 0.0F);
  }
  
  protected void preRenderCallback(AbstractClientPlayer entitylivingbaseIn, float partialTickTime) {
    float f = 0.9375F;
    GlStateManager.scale(f, f, f);
  }
  
  protected void renderOffsetLivingLabel(AbstractClientPlayer entityIn, double x, double y, double z, String str, float p_177069_9_, double p_177069_10_) {
    if (p_177069_10_ < 100.0D) {
      Scoreboard scoreboard = entityIn.getWorldScoreboard();
      ScoreObjective scoreobjective = scoreboard.getObjectiveInDisplaySlot(2);
      if (scoreobjective != null) {
        Score score = scoreboard.getValueFromObjective(entityIn.getName(), scoreobjective);
        renderLivingLabel(entityIn, score.getScorePoints() + " " + scoreobjective.getDisplayName(), x, y, z, 64);
        y += ((getFontRendererFromRenderManager()).FONT_HEIGHT * 1.15F * p_177069_9_);
      } 
    } 
    super.renderOffsetLivingLabel(entityIn, x, y, z, str, p_177069_9_, p_177069_10_);
  }
  
  public void renderRightArm(AbstractClientPlayer clientPlayer) {
    float f = 1.0F;
    GlStateManager.color(f, f, f);
    ModelPlayer modelplayer = getMainModel();
    setModelVisibilities(clientPlayer);
    modelplayer.swingProgress = 0.0F;
    modelplayer.isSneak = false;
    modelplayer.setRotationAngles(0.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F, 0.0625F, (Entity)clientPlayer);
    modelplayer.renderRightArm();
  }
  
  public void renderLeftArm(AbstractClientPlayer clientPlayer) {
    float f = 1.0F;
    GlStateManager.color(f, f, f);
    ModelPlayer modelplayer = getMainModel();
    setModelVisibilities(clientPlayer);
    modelplayer.isSneak = false;
    modelplayer.swingProgress = 0.0F;
    modelplayer.setRotationAngles(0.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F, 0.0625F, (Entity)clientPlayer);
    modelplayer.renderLeftArm();
  }
  
  protected void renderLivingAt(AbstractClientPlayer entityLivingBaseIn, double x, double y, double z) {
    if (entityLivingBaseIn.isEntityAlive() && entityLivingBaseIn.isPlayerSleeping()) {
      super.renderLivingAt(entityLivingBaseIn, x + entityLivingBaseIn.renderOffsetX, y + entityLivingBaseIn.renderOffsetY, z + entityLivingBaseIn.renderOffsetZ);
    } else {
      super.renderLivingAt(entityLivingBaseIn, x, y, z);
    } 
  }
  
  protected void rotateCorpse(AbstractClientPlayer bat, float p_77043_2_, float p_77043_3_, float partialTicks) {
    if (bat.isEntityAlive() && bat.isPlayerSleeping()) {
      GlStateManager.rotate(bat.getBedOrientationInDegrees(), 0.0F, 1.0F, 0.0F);
      GlStateManager.rotate(getDeathMaxRotation(bat), 0.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F);
      GlStateManager.rotate(270.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F, 0.0F);
    } else {
      super.rotateCorpse(bat, p_77043_2_, p_77043_3_, partialTicks);
    } 
  }
}
```

Line where Error is specifically called:

```java
public ModelPlayer getMainModel() {
    return (ModelPlayer)super.getMainModel();
}
```

Other Classes you may need:

```java
package net.minecraft.client.renderer;

import net.minecraft.block.Block;
import net.minecraft.block.material.Material;
import net.minecraft.block.state.IBlockState;
import net.minecraft.client.Minecraft;
import net.minecraft.client.entity.AbstractClientPlayer;
import net.minecraft.client.entity.EntityPlayerSP;
import net.minecraft.client.renderer.block.model.ItemCameraTransforms;
import net.minecraft.client.renderer.entity.Render;
import net.minecraft.client.renderer.entity.RenderItem;
import net.minecraft.client.renderer.entity.RenderManager;
import net.minecraft.client.renderer.entity.RenderPlayer;
import net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.TextureAtlasSprite;
import net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.TextureMap;
import net.minecraft.client.renderer.vertex.DefaultVertexFormats;
import net.minecraft.entity.Entity;
import net.minecraft.entity.EntityLivingBase;
import net.minecraft.init.Items;
import net.minecraft.item.EnumAction;
import net.minecraft.item.Item;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemStack;
import net.minecraft.util.BlockPos;
import net.minecraft.util.EnumWorldBlockLayer;
import net.minecraft.util.MathHelper;
import net.minecraft.util.ResourceLocation;
import net.minecraft.world.World;
import net.minecraft.world.storage.MapData;
import optifine.Config;
import optifine.DynamicLights;
import optifine.Reflector;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import shadersmod.client.Shaders;

public class ItemRenderer {
  private static final ResourceLocation RES_MAP_BACKGROUND = new ResourceLocation("textures/map/map_background.png");
  
  private static final ResourceLocation RES_UNDERWATER_OVERLAY = new ResourceLocation("textures/misc/underwater.png");
  
  private final Minecraft mc;
  
  private ItemStack itemToRender;
  
  private float equippedProgress;
  
  private float prevEquippedProgress;
  
  private final RenderManager renderManager;
  
  private final RenderItem itemRenderer;
  
  private int equippedItemSlot = -1;
  
  private static final String __OBFID = "CL_00000953";
  
  public ItemRenderer(Minecraft mcIn) {
    this.mc = mcIn;
    this.renderManager = mcIn.getRenderManager();
    this.itemRenderer = mcIn.getRenderItem();
  }
  
  public void renderItem(EntityLivingBase entityIn, ItemStack heldStack, ItemCameraTransforms.TransformType transform) {
    if (heldStack != null) {
      Item item = heldStack.getItem();
      Block block = Block.getBlockFromItem(item);
      GlStateManager.pushMatrix();
      if (this.itemRenderer.shouldRenderItemIn3D(heldStack)) {
        GlStateManager.scale(2.0F, 2.0F, 2.0F);
        if (isBlockTranslucent(block) && (!Config.isShaders() || !Shaders.renderItemKeepDepthMask))
          GlStateManager.depthMask(false); 
      } 
      this.itemRenderer.renderItemModelForEntity(heldStack, entityIn, transform);
      if (isBlockTranslucent(block))
        GlStateManager.depthMask(true); 
      GlStateManager.popMatrix();
    } 
  }
  
  private boolean isBlockTranslucent(Block blockIn) {
    return (blockIn != null && blockIn.getBlockLayer() == EnumWorldBlockLayer.TRANSLUCENT);
  }
  
  private void func_178101_a(float angle, float p_178101_2_) {
    GlStateManager.pushMatrix();
    GlStateManager.rotate(angle, 1.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F);
    GlStateManager.rotate(p_178101_2_, 0.0F, 1.0F, 0.0F);
    RenderHelper.enableStandardItemLighting();
    GlStateManager.popMatrix();
  }
  
  private void func_178109_a(AbstractClientPlayer clientPlayer) {
    int i = this.mc.theWorld.getCombinedLight(new BlockPos(clientPlayer.posX, clientPlayer.posY + clientPlayer.getEyeHeight(), clientPlayer.posZ), 0);
    if (Config.isDynamicLights())
      i = DynamicLights.getCombinedLight(this.mc.getRenderViewEntity(), i); 
    float f = (i & 0xFFFF);
    float f1 = (i >> 16);
    OpenGlHelper.setLightmapTextureCoords(OpenGlHelper.lightmapTexUnit, f, f1);
  }
  
  private void func_178110_a(EntityPlayerSP entityplayerspIn, float partialTicks) {
    float f = entityplayerspIn.prevRenderArmPitch + (entityplayerspIn.renderArmPitch - entityplayerspIn.prevRenderArmPitch) * partialTicks;
    float f1 = entityplayerspIn.prevRenderArmYaw + (entityplayerspIn.renderArmYaw - entityplayerspIn.prevRenderArmYaw) * partialTicks;
    GlStateManager.rotate((entityplayerspIn.rotationPitch - f) * 0.1F, 1.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F);
    GlStateManager.rotate((entityplayerspIn.rotationYaw - f1) * 0.1F, 0.0F, 1.0F, 0.0F);
  }
  
  private float func_178100_c(float p_178100_1_) {
    float f = 1.0F - p_178100_1_ / 45.0F + 0.1F;
    f = MathHelper.clamp_float(f, 0.0F, 1.0F);
    f = -MathHelper.cos(f * 3.1415927F) * 0.5F + 0.5F;
    return f;
  }
  
  private void renderRightArm(RenderPlayer renderPlayerIn) {
    GlStateManager.pushMatrix();
    GlStateManager.rotate(54.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F, 0.0F);
    GlStateManager.rotate(64.0F, 1.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F);
    GlStateManager.rotate(-62.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F);
    GlStateManager.translate(0.25F, -0.85F, 0.75F);
    renderPlayerIn.renderRightArm((AbstractClientPlayer)this.mc.thePlayer);
    GlStateManager.popMatrix();
  }
  
  private void renderLeftArm(RenderPlayer renderPlayerIn) {
    GlStateManager.pushMatrix();
    GlStateManager.rotate(92.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F, 0.0F);
    GlStateManager.rotate(45.0F, 1.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F);
    GlStateManager.rotate(41.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F);
    GlStateManager.translate(-0.3F, -1.1F, 0.45F);
    renderPlayerIn.renderLeftArm((AbstractClientPlayer)this.mc.thePlayer);
    GlStateManager.popMatrix();
  }
  
  private void renderPlayerArms(AbstractClientPlayer clientPlayer) {
    this.mc.getTextureManager().bindTexture(clientPlayer.getLocationSkin());
    Render render = this.renderManager.getEntityRenderObject((Entity)this.mc.thePlayer);
    RenderPlayer renderplayer = (RenderPlayer)render;
    if (!clientPlayer.isInvisible()) {
      GlStateManager.disableCull();
      renderRightArm(renderplayer);
      renderLeftArm(renderplayer);
      GlStateManager.enableCull();
    } 
  }
  
  private void renderItemMap(AbstractClientPlayer clientPlayer, float p_178097_2_, float p_178097_3_, float p_178097_4_) {
    float f = -0.4F * MathHelper.sin(MathHelper.sqrt_float(p_178097_4_) * 3.1415927F);
    float f1 = 0.2F * MathHelper.sin(MathHelper.sqrt_float(p_178097_4_) * 3.1415927F * 2.0F);
    float f2 = -0.2F * MathHelper.sin(p_178097_4_ * 3.1415927F);
    GlStateManager.translate(f, f1, f2);
    float f3 = func_178100_c(p_178097_2_);
    GlStateManager.translate(0.0F, 0.04F, -0.72F);
    GlStateManager.translate(0.0F, p_178097_3_ * -1.2F, 0.0F);
    GlStateManager.translate(0.0F, f3 * -0.5F, 0.0F);
    GlStateManager.rotate(90.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F, 0.0F);
    GlStateManager.rotate(f3 * -85.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F);
    GlStateManager.rotate(0.0F, 1.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F);
    renderPlayerArms(clientPlayer);
    float f4 = MathHelper.sin(p_178097_4_ * p_178097_4_ * 3.1415927F);
    float f5 = MathHelper.sin(MathHelper.sqrt_float(p_178097_4_) * 3.1415927F);
    GlStateManager.rotate(f4 * -20.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F, 0.0F);
    GlStateManager.rotate(f5 * -20.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F);
    GlStateManager.rotate(f5 * -80.0F, 1.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F);
    GlStateManager.scale(0.38F, 0.38F, 0.38F);
    GlStateManager.rotate(90.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F, 0.0F);
    GlStateManager.rotate(180.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F);
    GlStateManager.rotate(0.0F, 1.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F);
    GlStateManager.translate(-1.0F, -1.0F, 0.0F);
    GlStateManager.scale(0.015625F, 0.015625F, 0.015625F);
    this.mc.getTextureManager().bindTexture(RES_MAP_BACKGROUND);
    Tessellator tessellator = Tessellator.getInstance();
    WorldRenderer worldrenderer = tessellator.getWorldRenderer();
    GL11.glNormal3f(0.0F, 0.0F, -1.0F);
    worldrenderer.begin(7, DefaultVertexFormats.POSITION_TEX);
    worldrenderer.pos(-7.0D, 135.0D, 0.0D).tex(0.0D, 1.0D).endVertex();
    worldrenderer.pos(135.0D, 135.0D, 0.0D).tex(1.0D, 1.0D).endVertex();
    worldrenderer.pos(135.0D, -7.0D, 0.0D).tex(1.0D, 0.0D).endVertex();
    worldrenderer.pos(-7.0D, -7.0D, 0.0D).tex(0.0D, 0.0D).endVertex();
    tessellator.draw();
    MapData mapdata = Items.filled_map.getMapData(this.itemToRender, (World)this.mc.theWorld);
    if (mapdata != null)
      this.mc.entityRenderer.getMapItemRenderer().renderMap(mapdata, false); 
  }
  
  private void func_178095_a(AbstractClientPlayer clientPlayer, float p_178095_2_, float p_178095_3_) {
    float f = -0.3F * MathHelper.sin(MathHelper.sqrt_float(p_178095_3_) * 3.1415927F);
    float f1 = 0.4F * MathHelper.sin(MathHelper.sqrt_float(p_178095_3_) * 3.1415927F * 2.0F);
    float f2 = -0.4F * MathHelper.sin(p_178095_3_ * 3.1415927F);
    GlStateManager.translate(f, f1, f2);
    GlStateManager.translate(0.64000005F, -0.6F, -0.71999997F);
    GlStateManager.translate(0.0F, p_178095_2_ * -0.6F, 0.0F);
    GlStateManager.rotate(45.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F, 0.0F);
    float f3 = MathHelper.sin(p_178095_3_ * p_178095_3_ * 3.1415927F);
    float f4 = MathHelper.sin(MathHelper.sqrt_float(p_178095_3_) * 3.1415927F);
    GlStateManager.rotate(f4 * 70.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F, 0.0F);
    GlStateManager.rotate(f3 * -20.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F);
    this.mc.getTextureManager().bindTexture(clientPlayer.getLocationSkin());
    GlStateManager.translate(-1.0F, 3.6F, 3.5F);
    GlStateManager.rotate(120.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F);
    GlStateManager.rotate(200.0F, 1.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F);
    GlStateManager.rotate(-135.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F, 0.0F);
    GlStateManager.scale(1.0F, 1.0F, 1.0F);
    GlStateManager.translate(5.6F, 0.0F, 0.0F);
    Render render = this.renderManager.getEntityRenderObject((Entity)this.mc.thePlayer);
    GlStateManager.disableCull();
    RenderPlayer renderplayer = (RenderPlayer)render;
    renderplayer.renderRightArm((AbstractClientPlayer)this.mc.thePlayer);
    GlStateManager.enableCull();
  }
  
  private void func_178105_d(float p_178105_1_) {
    float f = -0.4F * MathHelper.sin(MathHelper.sqrt_float(p_178105_1_) * 3.1415927F);
    float f1 = 0.2F * MathHelper.sin(MathHelper.sqrt_float(p_178105_1_) * 3.1415927F * 2.0F);
    float f2 = -0.2F * MathHelper.sin(p_178105_1_ * 3.1415927F);
    GlStateManager.translate(f, f1, f2);
  }
  
  private void func_178104_a(AbstractClientPlayer clientPlayer, float p_178104_2_) {
    float f = clientPlayer.getItemInUseCount() - p_178104_2_ + 1.0F;
    float f1 = f / this.itemToRender.getMaxItemUseDuration();
    float f2 = MathHelper.abs(MathHelper.cos(f / 4.0F * 3.1415927F) * 0.1F);
    if (f1 >= 0.8F)
      f2 = 0.0F; 
    GlStateManager.translate(0.0F, f2, 0.0F);
    float f3 = 1.0F - (float)Math.pow(f1, 27.0D);
    GlStateManager.translate(f3 * 0.6F, f3 * -0.5F, f3 * 0.0F);
    GlStateManager.rotate(f3 * 90.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F, 0.0F);
    GlStateManager.rotate(f3 * 10.0F, 1.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F);
    GlStateManager.rotate(f3 * 30.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F);
  }
  
  private void transformFirstPersonItem(float equipProgress, float swingProgress) {
    boolean displayLegacyAnimations = true;
    if (displayLegacyAnimations && this.mc != null && this.mc.thePlayer != null && this.mc.thePlayer.getItemInUse() != null && this.mc.thePlayer.getItemInUse().getItem() != null && Item.getIdFromItem(this.mc.thePlayer.getItemInUse().getItem()) == 261)
      GlStateManager.translate(-0.01F, 0.05F, -0.06F); 
    if (displayLegacyAnimations && this.mc != null && this.mc.thePlayer != null && this.mc.thePlayer.getCurrentEquippedItem() != null && this.mc.thePlayer.getCurrentEquippedItem().getItem() != null && Item.getIdFromItem(this.mc.thePlayer.getCurrentEquippedItem().getItem()) == 346) {
      GlStateManager.translate(0.08F, -0.027F, -0.33F);
      GlStateManager.scale(0.93F, 1.0F, 1.0F);
    } 
    if (displayLegacyAnimations && this.mc != null && this.mc.thePlayer != null && this.mc.thePlayer.isSwingInProgress && this.mc.thePlayer.getCurrentEquippedItem() != null && !this.mc.thePlayer.isEating() && !this.mc.thePlayer.isBlocking()) {
      GlStateManager.scale(0.85F, 0.85F, 0.85F);
      GlStateManager.translate(-0.078F, 0.003F, 0.05F);
    } 
    GlStateManager.translate(0.56F, -0.52F, -0.71999997F);
    GlStateManager.translate(0.0F, equipProgress * -0.6F, 0.0F);
    GlStateManager.rotate(45.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F, 0.0F);
    float f = MathHelper.sin(swingProgress * swingProgress * 3.1415927F);
    float f1 = MathHelper.sin(MathHelper.sqrt_float(swingProgress) * 3.1415927F);
    GlStateManager.rotate(f * -20.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F, 0.0F);
    GlStateManager.rotate(f1 * -20.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F);
    GlStateManager.rotate(f1 * -80.0F, 1.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F);
    GlStateManager.scale(0.4F, 0.4F, 0.4F);
  }
  
  private void func_178098_a(float p_178098_1_, AbstractClientPlayer clientPlayer) {
    GlStateManager.rotate(-18.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F);
    GlStateManager.rotate(-12.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F, 0.0F);
    GlStateManager.rotate(-8.0F, 1.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F);
    GlStateManager.translate(-0.9F, 0.2F, 0.0F);
    float f = this.itemToRender.getMaxItemUseDuration() - clientPlayer.getItemInUseCount() - p_178098_1_ + 1.0F;
    float f1 = f / 20.0F;
    f1 = (f1 * f1 + f1 * 2.0F) / 3.0F;
    if (f1 > 1.0F)
      f1 = 1.0F; 
    if (f1 > 0.1F) {
      float f2 = MathHelper.sin((f - 0.1F) * 1.3F);
      float f3 = f1 - 0.1F;
      float f4 = f2 * f3;
      GlStateManager.translate(f4 * 0.0F, f4 * 0.01F, f4 * 0.0F);
    } 
    GlStateManager.translate(f1 * 0.0F, f1 * 0.0F, f1 * 0.1F);
    GlStateManager.scale(1.0F, 1.0F, 1.0F + f1 * 0.2F);
  }
  
  private void func_178103_d() {
    GlStateManager.translate(-0.5F, 0.2F, 0.0F);
    GlStateManager.rotate(30.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F, 0.0F);
    GlStateManager.rotate(-80.0F, 1.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F);
    GlStateManager.rotate(60.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F, 0.0F);
  }
  
  public void renderItemInFirstPerson(float partialTicks) {
    float f = 1.0F - this.prevEquippedProgress + (this.equippedProgress - this.prevEquippedProgress) * partialTicks;
    EntityPlayerSP entityplayersp = this.mc.thePlayer;
    float f1 = entityplayersp.getSwingProgress(partialTicks);
    float f2 = entityplayersp.prevRotationPitch + (entityplayersp.rotationPitch - entityplayersp.prevRotationPitch) * partialTicks;
    float f3 = entityplayersp.prevRotationYaw + (entityplayersp.rotationYaw - entityplayersp.prevRotationYaw) * partialTicks;
    func_178101_a(f2, f3);
    func_178109_a((AbstractClientPlayer)entityplayersp);
    func_178110_a(entityplayersp, partialTicks);
    GlStateManager.enableRescaleNormal();
    GlStateManager.pushMatrix();
    if (this.itemToRender != null) {
      if (this.itemToRender.getItem() instanceof net.minecraft.item.ItemMap) {
        renderItemMap((AbstractClientPlayer)entityplayersp, f2, f, f1);
      } else if (entityplayersp.getItemInUseCount() > 0) {
        EnumAction enumaction = this.itemToRender.getItemUseAction();
        switch (ItemRenderer$1.field_178094_a[enumaction.ordinal()]) {
          case 1:
            transformFirstPersonItem(f, entityplayersp.getSwingProgress(partialTicks));
            break;
          case 2:
          case 3:
            func_178104_a((AbstractClientPlayer)entityplayersp, partialTicks);
            transformFirstPersonItem(f, entityplayersp.getSwingProgress(partialTicks));
            break;
          case 4:
            transformFirstPersonItem(f, entityplayersp.getSwingProgress(partialTicks));
            func_178103_d();
            break;
          case 5:
            transformFirstPersonItem(f, entityplayersp.getSwingProgress(partialTicks));
            func_178098_a(partialTicks, (AbstractClientPlayer)entityplayersp);
            break;
        } 
      } else {
        func_178105_d(f1);
        transformFirstPersonItem(f, f1);
      } 
      renderItem((EntityLivingBase)entityplayersp, this.itemToRender, ItemCameraTransforms.TransformType.FIRST_PERSON);
    } else if (!entityplayersp.isInvisible()) {
      func_178095_a((AbstractClientPlayer)entityplayersp, f, f1);
    } 
    GlStateManager.popMatrix();
    GlStateManager.disableRescaleNormal();
    RenderHelper.disableStandardItemLighting();
  }
  
  public void renderOverlays(float partialTicks) {
    GlStateManager.disableAlpha();
    if (this.mc.thePlayer.isEntityInsideOpaqueBlock()) {
      IBlockState iblockstate = this.mc.theWorld.getBlockState(new BlockPos((Entity)this.mc.thePlayer));
      BlockPos blockpos = new BlockPos((Entity)this.mc.thePlayer);
      EntityPlayerSP entityplayersp = this.mc.thePlayer;
      for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        double d0 = entityplayersp.posX + ((((i >> 0) % 2) - 0.5F) * entityplayersp.width * 0.8F);
        double d1 = entityplayersp.posY + ((((i >> 1) % 2) - 0.5F) * 0.1F);
        double d2 = entityplayersp.posZ + ((((i >> 2) % 2) - 0.5F) * entityplayersp.width * 0.8F);
        BlockPos blockpos1 = new BlockPos(d0, d1 + entityplayersp.getEyeHeight(), d2);
        IBlockState iblockstate1 = this.mc.theWorld.getBlockState(blockpos1);
        if (iblockstate1.getBlock().isVisuallyOpaque()) {
          iblockstate = iblockstate1;
          blockpos = blockpos1;
        } 
      } 
      Object object = Reflector.getFieldValue(Reflector.RenderBlockOverlayEvent_OverlayType_BLOCK);
      if (iblockstate.getBlock().getRenderType() != -1 && !Reflector.callBoolean(Reflector.ForgeEventFactory_renderBlockOverlay, new Object[] { this.mc.thePlayer, Float.valueOf(partialTicks), object, iblockstate, blockpos }))
        func_178108_a(partialTicks, this.mc.getBlockRendererDispatcher().getBlockModelShapes().getTexture(iblockstate)); 
    } 
    if (!this.mc.thePlayer.isSpectator()) {
      if (this.mc.thePlayer.isInsideOfMaterial(Material.water) && !Reflector.callBoolean(Reflector.ForgeEventFactory_renderWaterOverlay, new Object[] { this.mc.thePlayer, Float.valueOf(partialTicks) }))
        renderWaterOverlayTexture(partialTicks); 
      if (this.mc.thePlayer.isBurning() && !Reflector.callBoolean(Reflector.ForgeEventFactory_renderFireOverlay, new Object[] { this.mc.thePlayer, Float.valueOf(partialTicks) }))
        renderFireInFirstPerson(partialTicks); 
    } 
    GlStateManager.enableAlpha();
  }
  
  private void func_178108_a(float p_178108_1_, TextureAtlasSprite p_178108_2_) {
    this.mc.getTextureManager().bindTexture(TextureMap.locationBlocksTexture);
    Tessellator tessellator = Tessellator.getInstance();
    WorldRenderer worldrenderer = tessellator.getWorldRenderer();
    float f = 0.1F;
    GlStateManager.color(0.1F, 0.1F, 0.1F, 0.5F);
    GlStateManager.pushMatrix();
    float f1 = -1.0F;
    float f2 = 1.0F;
    float f3 = -1.0F;
    float f4 = 1.0F;
    float f5 = -0.5F;
    float f6 = p_178108_2_.getMinU();
    float f7 = p_178108_2_.getMaxU();
    float f8 = p_178108_2_.getMinV();
    float f9 = p_178108_2_.getMaxV();
    worldrenderer.begin(7, DefaultVertexFormats.POSITION_TEX);
    worldrenderer.pos(-1.0D, -1.0D, -0.5D).tex(f7, f9).endVertex();
    worldrenderer.pos(1.0D, -1.0D, -0.5D).tex(f6, f9).endVertex();
    worldrenderer.pos(1.0D, 1.0D, -0.5D).tex(f6, f8).endVertex();
    worldrenderer.pos(-1.0D, 1.0D, -0.5D).tex(f7, f8).endVertex();
    tessellator.draw();
    GlStateManager.popMatrix();
    GlStateManager.color(1.0F, 1.0F, 1.0F, 1.0F);
  }
'''
PS: If you need more pls tell me
```

Comment: Hint: please tell us which line in that huge amount of code gives the exception. And: don't expect that other people work through such amounts of code.

Comment: Agree with @GhostCat please, show an exact line of code, plus provide more detailed information. No one will read your code.

Comment: I always wrote down the line where the exception occurs

Comment: public ModelPlayer getMainModel() {
    return (ModelPlayer)super.getMainModel();
}

Comment: I thought it be easier to have all the code of the class, because you can't help me with just one line I guess. Therefore I prepared more code